# setContentView() does not see all of the layouts in my R.layout folder

Tags: android

Within one of my methods, I want to switch layouts into a secondary one. But for some reason, the setContentView can't see the layout in the folder. The following images show this:

[My layout folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAFkh.png)

[image: The image that appeared after I clicked the "Create layout named..." suggestion]

I then ran the code

```
setContentView(R.layout.saveg_w_name) //I know this name is correctly spelled and everything since I clicked the createLayout
```

And yet it still gives the cannot resolve symbol error. Is this a bug with android studio or am I doing something wrong

Comment: did you tried restarting your android studio ?

Comment: yep I am dumb. Thank you

Comment: Nope you are not... its actually a bug... I recommend you to update your android studio latest is 4.0 because if its occurring everytime you create a layout then its frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your android studio and again check.

If it still doesn't solve your issue, try invalidating caches.

> click **File(Menu)->Invalidate Caches/Restart**